# Laravel 5.1, failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a challenge uploading a file into `app/storage`. Upon uploading the file I get this error: 
 
`file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName\storage\app\folderName): failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

I tried using `chmod -R 777 storage/app`, but still have the same problem.

Would really like know how to solve this problem.

Comment: `chmod -R 777 storage/app` is a linux command, but you are running xampp on Windows, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: ohh, i did know that. So, could you suggest what I can do then? @Ben

Comment: Try to check folder permission for xamp apache user. You can do this by right click on folder, then it must looks like http://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/usb-drive-security.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Make sure apache has write access to PHP's temp folder (`C:\xampp\tmp\` usually) as well as all of `storage` (not just storage/app). Also, be sure the uploads folder actually exists (`C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName\storage\app\folderName`).

PHP first uploads files to the tmp folder, and then moves them into storage.

[Here's how to change permissions in Windows 7](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-7&faq=105).

Comment: Does `C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName\storage\app\folderName` exist?